# Magento deployment - transfer Customer, Product data from Live to Dev

Tags: magento

We took a copy of the production site 2 months ago and after a vast number of updates we're now ready to deploy it. However, during this time there has been new products, orders, customers added on the production site.

Does anyone know how we can copy all products, orders, and customer data from the production site to the development site without losing the relationship between them all? (I'm assuming we need to keep the product_id in tact)

To make things a bit more difficult, we have various configurable/grouped products which I've recently learned isn't handled by the default Magento import/export.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason why you don't clone/copy the complete live database. That's what I usually do every now and than, I am skipping the Log_ tables and the core_config tables though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid my advice is to manually work through each update to add it into the live site using the development site as a reference to guide you.

All your new files are a simple copy-over so you are left with entering lots of info via the Magento Admin; it might not take that long once you get into the swing of it.